# Error suddenly when compiling Desktop on Android Studio - all projects - nothing changed - LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl, android-studio, ide

I have just gone into Android Studio to open a project. It will run in Android but not my Desktop configuration.
Nothing of the code has been changed and I have now tried 3 projects, also a brand new project straight from the LibGDX Project Generator .jar file.

The error I get in Studio is: 
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:322)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:216)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

Process finished with exit code 0

Please can anybody help me here? thanks

Comment: Could you post the configuration settings that your Desktop project passes into LwjglApplication?

Comment: yeah i havent changed any. For example in my Snake game: com.megabro.snake.desktop.DesktopLauncher (class) ; E:\MyDevs\LibGDX\Snake\android\assets (working directory) ; desktop (classpath of module). They were the only things I had to manually configure

Comment: Also the only thing that changed was it prompt me to download the Android Repository revision (or something like that)

Comment: oh, also my Nvidia drivers have just updated today also if that could be causing this?

Comment: Now. Looking more carefully at that exception message, in this case it looks like something with LWJGL, and not with the desktop sub project. It's complaining about a null pointer. Post some info on your system: operating system, graphic card.

Comment: Does this work for you? I just won't use a resolution of 1920x1080, but that depends on your monitor/graphic card: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806017/libgdx-nullpointerexception-for-the-default-code If using software opengl results in the game showing on screen, then by sure your drivers are involved or suspect your GPU is... not suited to the job.

Comment: Probably driver related. [Libgdx's Github source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglGraphics.java) at LwjglGraphics.java:322 shows an exception thrown with the message "OpenGL is not supported by the video driver"

Comment: I confirm it was NVidia drivers. I couldnt roll back unfortunately as by coincidence I had just installed a fresh windows on the day the GPU update released. I have downloaded old drivers from their website and all is working. Just hope that this gets resolved so I can stay updated for GPU. BTW apparantely anything running on LWJGL will fail with these drivers I have read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After I updated my NVidia drivers yesterday, I noticed that all my LibGdx Projects caused the same exception you've written above. After a lot of research on google, I found many complaints from other players which had artifacts with the new driver version and a file from NVidia about current driver problems. I tryed to rollback to the previous version and now everything works fine again. Use your "Hardware Manager" -> "Graphics Adapters" -> [Your NVidia Card] -> "Roll Back Drivers". Then you can go on with your programming project.

[NVidia PDF](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/378.49/378.49-win10-win8-win7-desktop-release-notes.pdf) Page 14

[Problem Discusion](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/5pwfnh/driver_37849_faqdiscussion_thread/)